# How do I write an aggregate using mongoose feathers adapter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, aggregation, feathersjs

I'm new to feathersjs framework and try to write aggregation query it's not working properly.

```
hook.app.query = { 
   lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      localField:"serviceLocationId",
      foreignField:"serviceLocationId",
      as: "orders" 
   },
   match: { serviceLocationId : { $in: Array.from(new Set(reqArr)) } },
   limit: 14 
}

hook.app.service('servicelocations')
    .find(hook.app.query)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

Comment: There is quite a bit of information on Sequelize associations linked in https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/sequelize.html#associations-and-relations

Comment: give me some example @Daff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to use following way **service.Model.aggregate** then its working fine

```
function locations(hook) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        hook.app.service('location')
          .Model.aggregate(hook.app.query)
          .then(result => {
            resolve(result)
          }).catch(e=>{
            reject(e)
          })
      })
}
```

Comment: where do i use this functions ?

Comment: you need to mention after your service `hook.app.service('location')` call `.Model.aggregate(hook.app.query)`.  something like this. @stalin